# pfsense for its firewall capabilities on small network

Tags: router, security, firewall, port-forwarding, pfsense

I have a small home network of approximately 3 windows machines and 1 pfsense freeBSD (dell laptop):

[image]

**q1.** The cable modem is connected to the NON-internet port of the wireless router. **Is this the correct way to connect**?
**q2.** The pfsense machine is a dell laptop. It has just one NIC.  **Is there a way to implement this with just one NIC**?

If there does not exist an easy way to implement this solution with just 1 NIC, can you suggest to me the cheapest possible option for hardware?

Comment: The cable modem should be connected to the Wan port of the router. There is normally only one such port.

Comment: im not sure which one that is. there's the INTERNET port and 5 regular ports.

Comment: this is the router i have http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/routers/E1000

Comment: "Using an Ethernet cable (also called
a network or Internet cable), the Internet
port connects the Router to your Internet
connection, which is typically a cable or Digital
Subscriber Line (DSL) modem" from [Linksys E1000 User Guide](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/E1000_V10_UG_USA_NC-WEB,0.pdf)

Comment: According the the photo in the manual the correct port is labelled "Internet"

Comment: NO, there isn't a way to do it with one nic, unless you are using advanced hardware that supports VLANs, and dual-homed NICs.

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you very much. in that case how do i add another NIC to my laptop? would usb to ethernet work?

Comment: personally, I'd go down to the local low-end computer recycler in the area. You can make an effective router out of a really old PC, often for 30$ or so. it would likely be more stable than a laptop, but would probably use more power. otherwise yeah, a usb nic would work.

Comment: I noticed mention of a laptop..  It's not what people tend to do generally but I've used Anker USB 3.0 Ethernet Adapter in a laptop.  I heard it has a good chipset maybe RTL8153.

Answer (score 1):

While the laptop might be ultra-low power, you should consider just picking up a refurbished SFF PC like a Core2Duo.  Look for something made within the last 5 years as it's more likely to have good "idle" power saving levels.  Your firewall will spend a lot of time idle.

You can pickup refurb boxes from NewEgg/Amazon for $60-$100, plus a NIC for another $30-$75.  Try to find a unit which has Intel NICs (Lenovo M58p) and stick a second low-profile Intel NIC in it.  Mine only uses 38-40W idle and 50-60W under load.

The downside of a laptop + USB NICs is going to be bandwidth issues.  It will work fine as long as you're only trying to push maybe 20-30Mbps in across the USB NIC, but will probably have issues as you approach 100Mbps.